# BigQuery DML COUNT() across multiple tables

Tags: google-bigquery, dml

I'm looking for a mechanism to control the accuracy of data that I import daily on multiple BigQuery tables. Each table have similar format with a DATE and an ID column. The Table format looks like this:

```
Table_1
| DATE       | ID       |
| 2018-10-01 | A        |
| 2018-10-01 | B        |
| 2018-10-02 | A        |
| 2018-10-02 | B        |
| 2018-10-02 | C        |
```

What I want to control is the evolution of the number of IDs, through such kind of output table:

```
CONTROL_TABLE
| DATE       | COUNT(Table1.ID) | COUNT(Table2.ID) | COUNT(Table3.ID) |
| 2018-10-01 |                2 |           487654 |           675386 |
| 2018-10-02 |                3 |           488756 |           675447 |
```

I'm trying to do such through 1 single SQL query, but face several limits with the DML such as:

```
-> One single SELECT with all the tables jointed is out of question for performance purpose (20+ tables with millions lines) 
-> I was thinking of going through temporary tables, but it seems I cannot run Multiple DELETE + INSERT functions on several tables with DML
-> I cannot use a wildcard table as the output of the query
```

Would anyone have an idea how to get such result in an optimized way, ideally through 1 single query ?

Comment: I don't know how Bigquery works, but suggest you to do your second solution. You need to create a temporal table with defined columns (Data Tabl1, Table2, Tablen). So each table will update it's corresponding field for given date (`UPDATE XXX set tablen=_some_value_ where date = '2018-10-01'`).

Comment: Hi Valijon, Thanks your input. The problem I face with your solution: tables are updated on daily basis so I need not to increment the dates manually each day.

What I have done so far is create 20 temp tables I fill with the output of the following:

`SELECT
  DATE(TIMESTAMP) as DATE, COUNT(ID) as Table1_ID
FROM
Table1
GROUP BY  DATE
ORDER BY DATE `

Then once each 20 queries for the 20 tables are run, I run a last query UPDATE CONTROL_TABLE with UNION of all temp tables

But I'm sure there must be smarter way to proceed and I need to achieve all this in 1 single query

Comment: Hi Valijon, I finally managed it with your proposal, just used INSERT rather than UPDATE, but its finally an acceptable workaround. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Good work, you may publish your solution and will help if anyone has the same problem